# Bash: How to move the files from one directory to another directory based on the variables in the log file?

Tags: bash

I have a log file like:

```
/IE_copora/1987/07/14/0056700.xml.json 2
/IE_copora/2006/11/01/1801433.xml.json 3
```

The first column in the log file is a file path list and the second column is just a number.
I want to move the files recorded in the log file from the old path
`/IE_copora/1987/07/14/0056700.xml.json` 

to a new path like:

`/new_directory/1987/07/14/0056700.xml.json` 
based on the second column number in the log file( the file path with the second column number less than 10).

Comment: Not a DV, but I think this is because your question is really unclear, and is basically just another code request. Could you give an example of the new path you expect ? And, more importantly, could you show us what you tried so far ?

Comment: Added some explanation. Is it a little clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to read lines from your log file one by one.
Second get first and second field in the line in two variables.
Third, use case / esac statement in BASH/Shell to process what new location to move.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
   #Get first column/field - path
   from="$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)"
   firstfolder="$(echo $from | cut -d'/' -f1)" 

   #Get Second column - number
   number="$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)"

   case $num in
         1) 
           #When number is 1. I'll do this. This assumes you aleady
           #where $firstfolder exists.
           mv $firstfolder  new_directory1

         2)  
           #When number is 2. I'll do that. This assumes you aleady
           #where $firstfolder exists.
           mv $firstfolder  new_directory2

         3) 
           #When number is 3. I'll do this/that. This assumes you aleady
           #where $firstfolder exists.
           mv $firstfolder  new_directory3

         #4) ..
         #5) ..
         #..) ..
         #9) ..

         *) 
           #This is when number is not between 1 - 9.
           echo "-- oh oh, I got you a dollar !!! - File: $first"
    esac
done < someTextLogFile.txt
```

For more info, learn BASH yourself from online.

A good example on how to use case statement is: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html